# Is there any simple way to fill a new color in adobe xd without opening the color fill bar?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, website-design, interface-design, adobe-xd

I am new to xd and I am working on multiple screens at a time, where I need to change the text color again and again.

So by opening the fill bar and changing the color is little time consuming, can I achieve the same by using any shortcut key??

> Please note I know I can do the same by defining the color in my assets panel. But that way also is not helpful here since the primary color in assets panel is already defied.

Comment: I don't understand your question. You want to change the color of certain text but without opening the settings for it? Are the text boxes different? Do you want different colors? Do you want multiple colors on one text box? There is only one way to define the color without opening the settings, thats with the color eye tool.

Comment: Dear @Sbaliyev I want different colors in the same textbox, i.e. a combination of black color texts and some of them are blue.

Comment: In that case I would add the color as a favorite, when you highlight/select a word inside the textbox you can easily select the favorite color so it changes.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a shortcut for what you are asking. But "character styles" might be what you are looking for in regards to text.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bhx96DYFrQM

Likewise, for whole elements, look to "components". Changing a master component changes all of them – so long as you don't edit individual sub-components. But even then, you can RMB and revert to the main component.
https://helpx.adobe.com/xd/help/components1.html